# display two values on same cell one on right and 2nd left side of the cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, nsmutablearray

i want to display two values (one is string and other is integer).
like following
string1 00000 int1
string2 00000 int2
string3 00000 int3

0--> spaces

i know how to display 2 values on same cell,
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ -- %d",[splitArrayValue   objectAtIndex:row],IntegerValue];

but its show something like following
string1 00 int1
string2 00000 int2
string3 000 int3
not in proper alignment

i want to display this integer value in 2nd column on same row
is it Possible?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add two serparate `UILabels` into the cell, differentiating them by their tag.

```
// tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath
// ...
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCEll alloc] init] autorelease];

    CGRect leftF = CGRectMake(10, 5, 100, 30);
    CGRect rightF = CGRectMake(120, 5, 100, 30);

    UILabel * left = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:leftF] autorelease];
    left.tag = kLeftLabel; // assumming #define kLeftLabel 100 

    [cell.contentView addSubview:left];

    UILabel * right = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rightF] autorelease];
    right.tag = kRightLabel; // assumming #define kRightLabel 101 

    [cell.contentView addSubview:right];
}

UILabel * leftLabel = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWIthTag:kLeftLabel];
UILabel * rightLabel = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWIthTag:kRightLabel];

// now put your two values in these two distinct labels
```

Comment: left.tag = kLeftLabel;  right.tag = kRightLabel;  what is the need of this ??

Comment: It so you can call `viewWithTag:` later and access the labels ( a couple lines down )

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the code below.Hope it might help.

Take 2 mutable arrays say - array1 and array 2.

In viewDidLoad, Allocate the arrays and store the values in both the arrays.

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{

    array1=[NsMutableArray alloc]init];
    [array1 addObject:@"string1"];
    [array1 addObject:@"string2"];
    [array1 addObject:@"string3"];

    array2=[NsMutableArray alloc]init];
    [array2 addObject:@"int1"];
    [array2 addObject:@"int2"];
    [array2 addObject:@"int3"];
}
```

Then continue with code below in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2         reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text =[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text =[array2 objectAtIndex:IndexPath.row];

    return cell;

}
```